# UNION ALL returning error when one sub-query finds no results?

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT UID, COUNT( * ) *100 AS Points
FROM  `Visited` 
WHERE UID =  '25'
UNION ALL 
SELECT UID, COUNT( * ) *1000 AS Points
FROM  `Sites` 
WHERE UID =  '25'
UNION ALL 
SELECT UID, COUNT( * ) *1000 AS Points
FROM  `userTags` 
WHERE UID =  '25'
```

When I run it, and one of the subqueries finds no results I get:

```
#1048 - Column 'UID' cannot be null
```

I don't really understand the problem, running the subquery that gives no results alone works alright and displays:

```
UID  | POINTS
NULL    0
```

However the big query won't unite it for some reason. What could be the reason?

---- EDIT

Also if the three subqueries give results the query works fine. The only problem is where there are no results in one of them.

Comment: What value are you specifying as the parameter `$uid` when you get this error?

Comment: Could `$uid` be `null` when called from your code?

Comment: I can run the middle query with UID as NULL, and it gives two columns: UID: NULL, POINTS: 0. Using "aaaa" as UID, also gives the same results. So UID could actually be whatever.

Comment: This query would be invalid in other RDBMSs. Try replacing the select in all 3 branches with `SELECT MAX(UID) AS UID, COUNT( * ) *100 AS Points`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are no matching rows for `UID = 25`, however `COUNT(*)` still returns a row saying there are `0` matching rows. You can either remove the row by using an outer select where UID is not null, or more simply replace the `NULL`, like this:

```
SELECT UID, COUNT( * ) *100 AS Points
FROM  `Visited` 
WHERE UID =  '25'
UNION ALL 
SELECT ifnull(UID, '25'), COUNT( * ) *1000 AS Points
FROM  `Sites` 
WHERE UID =  '25'
UNION ALL 
SELECT UID, COUNT( * ) *1000 AS Points
FROM  `userTags` 
WHERE UID =  '25';
```

Of course, you would replace the `'25'` with `$uid` for running from your code.

Do the same for the other tables too if you think there's a chance there are no matching rows